# Contradiction in Stationarity of AR(1) under the condition that |Φ| < 1

Tags: time-series, probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, stationarity

Something must have gone wrong with my reasoning.

**UPDATE:** This is the answer to my question provided by Dr. Ben.

[Where is $|\theta|<1$ used in recursive method derivation of invertibility of MA(1)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/535533/where-is-theta1-used-in-recursive-method-derivation-of-invertibility-of-ma)

Given a zero-mean AR(1) process $\{X_t\}_{t \in T}$:

$X_t =  \phi X_{t-1} + \varepsilon_{t}$; $\{\varepsilon_t\}_{t \in T}$ is $WN(0, \sigma^2)$

There are infinitely many solutions satisfying the recursive equation above, and there is only one **stationary** solution which is $X_t = \Big[\sum_{i =0}^{+\infty} \phi^{i}L^{i}\Big]\varepsilon_t$.

Assume that $|\phi| < 1$, and $\{X_t\}_{t \in T}$ is constructed to be a **NON-STATIONARY** solution of the recursive equation above.

However, I found it contradictory that,

$X_t =  \phi X_{t-1} + \varepsilon_{t} \iff X_t - \phi X_{t-1} = \varepsilon_{t} \iff (1 - \phi L)X_t = \varepsilon_{t}$

As $|\phi| < 1$, $1 - \phi L$ is invertible, and $(1 - \phi L)^{-1} = \sum_{i =0}^{+\infty} \phi^{i}L^{i}$.

Therefore, $X_t = \Big[\sum_{i =0}^{+\infty} \phi^{i}L^{i}\Big]\varepsilon_t$, implying that $X_t$ is **STATIONARY**.

Is this a contradiction?

Comment: You might also be interested in this [closely related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/535533/).

Comment: @Ben I will read it. Your answers in other posts really enlighten me these days. Thank you so much!